# Tasm program error

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I need help with this assembly language program because this is my 1st time to try to write a program but I don't know how to start. Here's the question

*Write an assembly language program which allows the user to input a number of years (from 1 to 30) and then tells the user how many months, weeks, days, hours and minutes are there in that number of years.
Example 1: Input: Number of years: 1
Output: Months: 12
Weeks:  52
Days: 365
Hours: 8760
Minutes: 525600*

I got this from our laboratory manual and I try to make my own tasm but it is wrong and can't execute properly. It is the 1st exercise but again I don't know how to start the structure. I'm a beginner in programming and I want to become good in this program. Thank you and sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: What does your code that doesn't work look like? You need to ask a more specific question than "how do I write this program?".

Comment: You need to read a bit more of your assembler text book first.  It will show you the basics on which interrupts to call to get keyboard input, which to call to print to console, and the basic math operation instructions.  Trying to do the lab before reading anything in the book or attending class is not going to work.

Comment: Your first task is asking you to sew up a wound and you've never done anything medical before in your life. You'll need to find a more basic manual/tutorial, acquire the basic practical skills, solve a few small problems with these practical skills, then come back to look at solving this one

Comment: btw a good training manual will have all the answers at the back. A bad training manual will not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger to determine the appropriate missing values   .

Enter the results using an editor. Handwritten results are not acceptable.

```
TITLE  CS14PGM1:  DEBUGGER
        ; MY NAME IS (your name here).
        .MODEL  SMALL
        .STACK  100H
        .DATA
xx          db  0E5h
xx1         db  74h
yy          dw  0BB33h
A           DW   5599h
B         DW     -37
MESSAGE DB      '98765'
        .CODE
MAIN        PROC
        MOV    AX,  @DATA
        MOV      DS,   AX
        MOV    AX,  A
        MOV     AX,  0AABAH
        MOV     AL,   MESSAGE
        MOV     AX,   0AABAH
        MOV     AL,    BYTE  PTR  A
        MOV     AX,   WORD  PTR  xx1
        LEA     AX,   MESSAGE
        MOV     AX,   1237H
        MOV     AX,   B
        MOV     AX,   5234H
        MOV     AL,   -23
        MOV     BYTE  PTR  A,  -23
        MOV     A,   -23
        mov     al, byte ptr xx+1      ;  ax=
        mov     bl, byte ptr yy+1      ;  bx=
        mov     cx, word ptr  xx     ;  cx=
        mov     byte ptr xx, 0AAh      ;  xx=
        mov     byte ptr xx+1, 0BBh    ;  xx1=
        mov     word ptr xx, 0CCDDh    ;  xx=    xx1=
        mov     byte ptr yy, 22h       ;  yy=
        mov     byte ptr yy+1, 33h     ;  yy=
        mov     word ptr xx+1, 4455h   ;  xx=    xx1=    yy=
        mov     word ptr xx1,  0099h   ;  xx=    xx1=    yy=
        mov     word ptr a+1, 1234h    ;  A=       B=

        MOV     AX,  4C00H
        INT     21H
MAIN     ENDP
END      MAIN
```